# How to get a json with key->value from google spreadsheets?

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Now I am using this to get the data from sheet.

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/DOC_ID/values/!A2:Z999?key=API_KEY')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            console.log(json)
        });
```

And as a result I am getting an array of values - rows.

```
[Row Name1,Row Name2,Row Name3,],
[val11, val12, val13],
[val21, val22, val23],
[val31, val32, val33]
```

Is there a way to get this as key->value json? Like this one:

```
{
"Row Name1":"val11",
"Row Name2":"val12",
...
},
{
"Row Name1":"val21",
"Row Name2":"val22",
...
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, all Google Sheets API methods return (and accept) values as double arrays. Conversion to an array of objects would have to happen client-side, for example

```
var values = [["Row Name1", "Row Name2", "Row Name3"], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]; // sample values
var dict = values.slice(1).map(row => row.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[values[0][i]] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {}));
```